# Why does my 4k Dell monitor (connected to Dell laptop via Dell dock) switch from 60Hz to 30Hz intermittently after sleep?

Tags: external-display, displayport, refresh-rate

## Setting the Scene

I have the following setup:

[image: Connections]

Sometimes (and every time today) when the laptop is resumed from "sleep", the monitor has inexplicably changed from 60Hz to 30Hz.

When I first set all this up, I struggled to get 60Hz to work, and purely by accident made it work by going into the monitor's menu and messing with the Multi Stream Transport (MST) setting.

## The Workaround

When this happens, I have settled into an uncomfortable routine where I realise what's happened, then have to delve into the menu to turn MST on and back off. This causes the display to reset, which in turn moves the desktop back to the laptop screen and messes up my windows etc in the process, but means I get 60Hz back.

[image]

I would love to know why this is happening and stop it; it's utterly maddening!

## Further Information

- I could ditch the dock altogether, I suppose. I have to use a USB-A port on the laptop with a powered USB 3.0 hub because with all the things I have plugged-in (mouse, backlit keyboard, webcam, external soundcard, USB headset) along with the video signal, I used to get errors from Windows about USB bandwidth and devices would stop working. Although then I wouldn't be able to use the dock for a wired network connection, and would have to buy some USB-A->ethernet adapter for the the remaining USB-A port.

Comment: Try updating BIOS (UEFI), Chipset and Video drivers to see if that helps.

Comment: Yes all done. Updating drivers is step 2 after turning it off and on again, isn't it?

Comment: After you updated, tuned OFF and then started up what happen to Resolution?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Resolution does switch as the desktop is moving back to the built-in display and back again (despite both displays being 3840x2160), but I'm not sure what you mean by "after updated, turned off, and restarted". This has been happening for months, so the problem has survived many dozens of restarts.

Comment: So BIOS and Driver update then, did not help. That is what you are saying above.  I am not sure what else at this point.